Different information output from img.getexif() between windows and MAC M3?
Is there any idea why there is a different output from same code running in Mac M3 and windows ?
In windows output gives much more data including a lot of numbers which I need for some information however, for M3 result .. it is much less
I share the code but have no idea why ?
from PIL import Image, ExifTags
# Open the image
img = Image.open("MV_HFV_012.jpg")
img_exif = img.getexif()
x=str(img_exif)
print(x)

Version of pillow I use as the following:
Name: pillow
Version: 11.0.0
Summary: Python Imaging Library (Fork)
Home-page: https://python-pillow.org
Location: /opt/miniconda3/lib/python3.12/site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: colorthief, imageio, matplotlib, scikit-image

It would help if you showed the difference in output between the OSes, not just that "something is missing". You should also list the version of Python and Pillow you're using on both OSes, and how you've installed them.

@AKX
Thanks for your reply..
Unfortunately.. I do not have windows anymore right now.. so I can not show you the results from windows, but for example.. I got some information of the scale .. in windows the output was much much more.. compared to OSes.. so kindly any solution or suggestion ?It is too strange for me..
I modify the question to include version of Pillow

Without further info, no, I can't help. There should likely be no difference between platforms, as EXIF parsing is implemented in pure Python. Are you absolutely sure you're reading the exact same file on both platforms?
